# Need Help installing Bootloader

Tags: bootloader

I am trying to install ubuntu alongside Windows. I am installing on a different drive that does not have windows on it. I have partitioned the drive (the one im installing ubuntu on) so half is for ubuntu and half is for extra storage for windows.

I have read everywhere to install the bootloader on /dev/sda but there is a problem with that. My /dev/sda is an external drive I use for backups.

My Windows drive is /dev/sdb and the drive im installing ubuntu on is /dev/sdd. Which one do I install the bootloader on?

This is how my drives appear in the menu:

```
/dev/sda  Seagate Expansion Desk (2.0 TB)
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sdb  ATA PNY CS900 120GB (120.0 GB) [This is windows]
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb4
/dev/sdc  ATA WDC WD5000AVVS-6 (500.1 GB)
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdd  ATA WDC WD10EADX-22T (1.0 TB)
/dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd5 [ubuntu install partition]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs. If BIOS, then you want to only use Something else and choose sdd as drive to install grub into (never to partition).  And set BIOS to default boot from sdd so you can multiple boot from grub. But if Windows 10 you must have fast start up off and keep it off  as it may get turned back on with Windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer will install grub on the drive that Ubuntu is installed on by default. On your computer the device name of this drive is `/dev/sdd`. Accept the default and install grub on this drive, ATA WDC WD10EADX-22T (1.0 TB).